# Can "like" be followed by a complete sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> People can adapt to adverse situations, **just like** people living in dry
> areas are more adapted to aridity.

I think "like" should only be followed by a noun phrase. However, the above usage sounds right to me. Must I change "like" to "as"?

> People can adapt to adverse situations, **just as** people living in dry
> areas are more adapted to aridity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "like" as a conjuntion is common but informal. Wiktionary notes:

> The American Heritage Dictionary opines that using "like" as a conjunction, instead of "as", "the way", "as if", or "as though", is informal; it has, however, been routine since the Middle English period. AHD4 says "Writers since Chaucer's time have used like as a conjunction, but 19th-century and 20th-century critics have been so vehement in their condemnations of this usage that a writer who uses the construction in formal style risks being accused of illiteracy or worse", and recommends using "as" in formal speech and writing. OED does not tag it as colloquial or nonstandard, but notes, "Used as conj[unction]: = 'like as', as. Now generally condemned as vulgar or slovenly, though examples may be found in many recent writers of standing."

Your first is certainly fine in conversation, but since you know the formal alternative you probably should use "as" in an essay.

Answer (score 0):

> *People can adapt to adverse situations,* [*just like people living in dry*
> *areas are more adapted to aridity*].

It sounds fine to me, too.

The bracketed element is a comparative clause, where "like" is in competition with "as". It's an interesting question because unlike most comparative clauses it is structurally complete (non-expandable).

Perhaps that's the reason it shouldn't arouse too much criticism from authoritarian prescriptivists.

Comment: I don't understand how "it is structurally complete" gives it some legitimacy and forestall too much criticism.